# How can i prove that $w=az$ while a is real number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $z,w \in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, if $zw$ is real number, how can i prove that $w=az$ while $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You can't.${{}}$

Answer (score 3):

You don't. If $z=1+i$ and $w=1-i$, then $zw\in\mathbb{R}$, but there is no real $a$ such that $w=az$.

Comment: Thank you very much about your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question was to prove $\,w = a \,\color{red}{\bar z}\,$ instead, let $z w = \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$, then if $z \ne 0\,$:

$$
w = \frac{\lambda}{z} \cdot \frac{\bar z}{\bar z} = \frac{\lambda}{|z|^2} \cdot \bar z
$$

The above gives $w = a \cdot \bar z$ for the real value $a = \frac{\lambda}{|z|^2} \in \mathbb{R}\,$.